# Failed to use OpenID with Atlassian Crowd server in Play Framework 2?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, openid, atlassian-crowd

It looks like the default OpenID in Play 2 lost some parameters. Or else, Play 2 defaults to using OpenID 2 while Crowd uses OpenID 1.1?

Comment: OpenID in Play2 works well. I've been using it with Google as OpenId provider, never had a problem.  I suggest you checkout the Atlassian Crows configuration.

Comment: I found If I remove the url parameter :`openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspec
s.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0 ` and add parameter `openid.trust_root`,the request could work with crowd id server. and the openid.ns parameter is add by play api.

Comment: From Crowd 2.6, OpenID 2.0 is supported.

Answer (score 1):

From [Crowd 2.6](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CROWD/Crowd+2.6+Release+Notes), [OpenID 2.0 is supported](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CROWD/Crowd+2.6+Release+Notes#Crowd2.6ReleaseNotes-OpenIDimprovements). This should allow you to use it with Play's defaults.